# Extracting nested object in Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to extract IPv4 addresses for specific interface from hostvars in Ansible Jinja2 template without loops using.

Trying to extract 'ansible_eth1' object from hostvars is successful and Ansible provides me all info about `eth1' interface:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups['my_hosts'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_eth1') | join(', ') }}"
```

```
TASK [my_task : debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "active": true, 
            "device": "eth1", 
            ...
            "ipv4": {
                "address": "192.168.56.15", 
                "broadcast": "192.168.56.255", 
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0", 
                "network": "192.168.56.0"
            }, 
            ...
```

But if I try to extract nested object - 'ipv4.address' - it returns empty list:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups['my_hosts'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_eth1.ipv4.address') | join(', ') }}"
```

```
TASK [my_task : debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": ", "
}
ok: [server2] => {
    "msg": ", "
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are after is specified by the final line in the [`extract` section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers), where it says "The third argument to the filter can also be a list, for a recursive lookup inside the container"

Thus, in your case:

```
msg: "{{ groups['my_hosts']
       | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_eth1', 'ipv4', 'address'])
       | join(', ') }}"
```